# radio button is splitting in two lines when resize the page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have a radiobuttonlist on my web page. when I resize the page to make it smaller, the radio button comes on the top and the text of the radio button comes right underneath it. Below is screenshot of what I am getting:

[image]

When I resize the screen, can I see the radio button and text next to it and the text comes to the second line rather than text and radio button separately.

Below is my code:

```
    <style>

   .radioBL input[type="radio"] {
    margin-right: 10px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
    </style>
  <asp:RadioButtonList  CssClass="radioBL" ID="test" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem  Text="In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available."></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."></asp:ListItem>
          
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Below is the HTML for above code when I view the page source:

```
       <div style="margin-top: 70px;position:relative;top:50px">
        <div  style="background-color:white;border-radius:10px;align-content:center;align-self:center;vertical-align:middle;width:100%;" class="container body-content"   >
            
    <style>

   .radioBL input[type="radio"] {
    margin-right: 10px;
    
}

   .test1{
       word-break: break-all;
   }
    </style>
  <table id="MainContent_test" class="radioBL test1">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="MainContent_test_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$test" value="In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available." /><label for="MainContent_test_0">In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="MainContent_test_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$test" value="
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged." /><label for="MainContent_test_1">
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I modified my style sheet like so, but still seeing the break between radio button and the text:

```
    <style>

   .radioBL input[type="radio"] {
    margin-right: 10px;
    
}

label {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
    </style>
  <asp:RadioButtonList  CssClass="radioBL label" ID="test" runat="server" >
      <asp:ListItem CssClass="label"  Text="In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available."></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem CssClass="label"  Text="Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."></asp:ListItem>
          
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word;`? Or simply use some real sentence word instead of an unrealistic long string withour word-break?

Comment: well, in my actual application. I have a real sentence. I modified my example above with real string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this stylesheet with radio Buttons and it will work:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .radioBL input[type="radio"] {
        margin-right: 10px;
        word-break: break-all;
    }
 
    .radioBL label {
        display: inline !important;
    }
</style>



<asp:RadioButtonList  CssClass="radioBL" ID="test" runat="server" >
      <asp:ListItem CssClass="label"  Text="In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available."></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem CssClass="label"  Text="Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."></asp:ListItem>
          
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

you will see this when you run it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `word-wrap: break-word;` allows unbreakable words to be broken if they are too large .

You can achieve the same with `word-break: break-all;`

```css
label {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<label for="html"> <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="HTML"> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</label></td>
</label>
```

**Here is your `HTML` code for the problems solution you are seeking but can't help with `asp.net` way , pasted so that you can find some help**

```html
<div style="margin-top: 70px;position:relative;top:50px">
  <div style="background-color:white;border-radius:10px;align-content:center;align-self:center;vertical-align:middle;width:100%;" class="container body-content">

    <style>
      .radioBL input[type="radio"] {
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
      
      label {
        word-break: break-all;
      }
    </style>
    <table id="MainContent_test" class="radioBL test1">
      <tr>
        <td><label for="MainContent_test_0"><input id="MainContent_test_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$test" value="In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available."
          />In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="MainContent_test_1"><input id="MainContent_test_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$test" value="
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."
          />
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</label></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I tried to put word-wrap: break-word; and words rather than one long sentence. I am still getting radio button and text separately. Please see my post above. I modified the style sheet

Comment: If it be html then I would used `input` inside `label` tag and would have resolved above problem with `word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: its will translate to html on the web page. I can post the html if you want.

Comment: I have a huge line in real world. I posted this question because the line is big.

Comment: Posted the html in my original question.

Comment: Problem solved and added a snippet to demonstrate it

Comment: Try to remove the CSS to see effect of `word-wrap: break-word;` . Also try to put `input` outside `label` and see the changes

Comment: Not sure how to do this on my style sheet. I only have this:     .radioBL input[type="radio"] {
    margin-right: 10px;
    word-break: break-all;
}  I can put the stylesheet on radiobuttonlist or each list item.

Comment: Apply `word-break: break-all;` to `label` and put `input` inside `label`

Comment: write a extra css as used in snippet

Comment: somehow, it is still showing the radio button split with text. I posted the style sheet that I used in my original question. any help will be appreciated. I am sure I am doing something wrong. Can you please look at my stylesheet and the code.

Comment: Brother what I told you , put radio tag inside label

Comment: I can told you by html way but am not good in asp.net , so sorry can't help in asp.net way

Comment: HTML code is pasted in answer can't help with asp.net

Comment: I upvoted your answer.